# Incorrect syntax near ','. AND Incorrect syntax near ')'

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have some problem with brackets and I do not know where the error is.

```
DECLARE @theDate varchar(60)
DECLARE @theDay varchar(6)
DECLARE @theMonth varchar(6)
SET @theDate = GETDATE()
IF(CAST(DAY(@theDate)as int) > 9 ,SET @theDay = CAST(DAY(@theDate)as Varchar(6)), SET @theDay = '0' + CAST(DAY(@theDate)as Varchar(6)));
IF(CAST(DAY(@theDate)as int) > 9 ,SET @theMonth = CAST(MONTH(@theDate)as Varchar(6)), SET @theMonth = '0' + CAST(MONTH(@theDate)as Varchar(6)));
```

Error Message

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 13
Incorrect syntax near ','.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 13
Incorrect syntax near ','.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 13
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @theDate varchar(60)

DECLARE @theDay varchar(6)

DECLARE @theMonth varchar(6)

SET @theDate = GETDATE()

 IF(CAST(DAY(@theDate)as int) > 9 )

  SET @theDay = CAST(DAY(@theDate)as Varchar(6))

 else

  SET @theDay = '0' +( CAST(DAY(@theDate)as Varchar(6)));

IF(CAST(DAY(@theDate)as int) > 9 )

 SET @theMonth = CAST(MONTH(@theDate)as Varchar(6))

else

 SET @theMonth = '0' + (CAST(MONTH(@theDate)as Varchar(6)));
```

Please use proper if else syntax as above.

Answer (score 0):

You have used inappropriate parenthesis as well as commas. Moreover I have added `begin` and `end` for section definition.
Here is your working code

```
DECLARE @theDate varchar(60)
DECLARE @theDay varchar(6)
DECLARE @theMonth varchar(6)
SET @theDate = GETDATE()
IF(CAST(DAY(@theDate)as int)) > 9 
begin  
     SET @theDay = CAST(DAY(@theDate)as Varchar(6)) 
     set @theDay = '0' + CAST(DAY(@theDate)as Varchar(6)) 
end;
IF(CAST(DAY(@theDate)as int)) > 9 
begin 
     SET @theMonth = CAST(MONTH(@theDate)as Varchar(6)) 
     SET @theMonth = '0' +    CAST(MONTH(@theDate)as Varchar(6)) 
end;
```

To see the output add below lines to your code

```
select @theDay
select @theMonth
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply do it like this:

```
select DAY(GETDATE())
select MONTH(GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you shoul try this code.

```
DECLARE @theDate varchar(60)
DECLARE @theDay varchar(6)
DECLARE @theMonth varchar(6)

SET @theDate = GETDATE()

IF
  CAST(DAY(@theDate)as int) > 9
THEN
  SET @theDay = CAST(DAY(@theDate)as Varchar(6))
ELSE
  SET @theDay = '0' + CAST(DAY(@theDate)as Varchar(6))
END

IF
  CAST(DAY(@theDate)as int) > 9
THEN
  SET @theMonth = CAST(MONTH(@theDate)as Varchar(6))
ELSE
  SET @theMonth = '0' + CAST(MONTH(@theDate)as Varchar(6))
END
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using if in sql query,it is better to use Begin and End after the if loop.
You can Try this.

IF(CAST(DAY(@theDate)as int) > 9) 
Begin
SET @theDay = CAST(DAY(@theDate)as Varchar(6));
SET @theDay = '0' + CAST(DAY(@theDate)as Varchar(6));
End
IF(CAST(DAY(@theDate)as int) > 9)
BEGIN
SET @theMonth = CAST(MONTH(@theDate)as Varchar(6));
SET @theMonth = '0' + CAST(MONTH(@theDate)as Varchar(6));
END
END

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, that is not the syntax for the conditional statement. It should be:

```
DECLARE @theDate varchar(60)
DECLARE @theDay varchar(6)
DECLARE @theMonth varchar(6)
SET @theDate = GETDATE()

IF CAST(DAY(@theDate)as int) > 9 BEGIN
  SET @theDay = CAST(DAY(@theDate)as Varchar(6))
END
ELSE BEGIN
  SET @theDay = '0' + CAST(DAY(@theDate)as Varchar(6))
END
IF CAST(DAY(@theDate)as int) > 9 BEGIN
  SET @theMonth = CAST(MONTH(@theDate)as Varchar(6))
END
ELSE BEGIN
  SET @theMonth = '0' + CAST(MONTH(@theDate)as Varchar(6))
END
```

You tried to use a conditional as a function, you have the IIF function to do so, this is its syntax:

```
DECLARE @theDate varchar(60)
DECLARE @theDay varchar(6)
DECLARE @theMonth varchar(6)
SET @theDate = GETDATE()

SET @theDay = IIF(CAST(DAY(@theDate)as int) > 9, 
                  CAST(DAY(@theDate)as Varchar(6)), 
                  '0' + CAST(DAY(@theDate)as Varchar(6)));
SET @theMonth = IIF(CAST(DAY(@theDate)as int) > 9, 
                    CAST(MONTH(@theDate)as Varchar(6)), 
                    '0' + CAST(MONTH(@theDate)as Varchar(6)));
```

By the way, the easiest way to padding with leading zeros is to use the format function:

```
DECLARE @theDate varchar(60)
DECLARE @theDay varchar(6)
DECLARE @theMonth varchar(6)

SET @theDate = GETDATE()
set @theDay = Format(DAY(@theDate), '00')
set @theMonth = Format(MONTH(@theDate), '00')
```